# Showing the DirectoryIndex in the URL with Apache

Tags: apache

Is there a way to show the DirectoryIndex file in the URL as default? For example, if the DirectoryIndex is index.html, when I typed in www.someurl.com, it would automatically display www.someurl.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that there’s an option to trigger Apache to do this automatically.

But if you know the index document, you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect such requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```